# Create list items from uploaded excel spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am fairly new to doing anything in SharePoint, other than basic operations.  I have been tasked with creating a SharePoint 2013 site with the following operations:

1. Upload a selected Excel Spreadsheet.
2. Create a list item from each row in the spreadsheet, after some basic processing that was originally done using VBA in Excel.

Would I create a Library, upload the file, and then add some code that would do the processing?  If so, where would I put the code and what would it look like?

I think that if I could get the file uploaded successfully and then open the spreadsheet, I can figure out the rest.  Could be incorrect, though.  Can anyone help me out here?

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint lets you import an Excel file when creating a list. Each row of your Excel file will become a row in your SharePoint list, as shown below:
[image]

Full procedure is described on Microsoft web site [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-list-based-on-a-spreadsheet-380cfeb5-6e14-438e-988a-c2b9bea574fa?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1).